# If $(2^n+1)\theta=\pi$, $2^n\cos\theta \cos2\theta\cos2^2\theta \cdots\cos2^{n-1}\theta=$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $(2^n+1)\theta=\pi$, $2^n\cos\theta \cos2\theta \cos2^2\theta \cdots\cos2^{n-1}\theta=$

A)-1

B)1

C)1/2

D)none

If I take $\sin$ on both sides 
$$\sin(2^n+1)\theta=\sin\pi$$
Since $\sin\pi=0$
$$(2^n+1)\theta=0$$
$$\theta=0$$ and $$2^n+1=0$$
$$2^n=-1$$

So in the first equation, every value of cos will become 1 as $\cos0$ is always 1.

$2^n=-1$
So $(-1)1=-1$

But the answer is 1, so what is wrong with my process.

Comment: With the same argument, since $\sin\pi=0$ you'd conclude that $\pi=0$.

Comment: My idea:
$$
2^k \theta + \theta = \pi
$$
and therefore
$$
\cos{\left( 2^t \theta \right)} = \cos{(\pi - \theta)}
$$
for integers $k$ and $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that

> $$2^n\cos\theta\cos2\theta\cos2^2\theta\cdots\cos2^{n-1}\theta = \frac{\sin2^n\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

As we have $(2^n+1)\theta = \pi \implies2^n\theta = \pi-\theta, \theta\ne0$

So,

> $$2^n\cos\theta\cos2\theta\cos2^2\theta\cdots\cos2^{n-1}\theta=\frac{\sin2^n\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{\sin(\pi-\theta)}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}=1 \ $$

Comment: It is impossible for $\theta=k\pi$.

Comment: I've mentioned it

Comment: I mean that you do not even have to mention because it will never be the case.

Comment: I understood it. Thanks!